# Vapor 2 Validation Valid-Type throws "Use of undeclared type Valid"

Tags: validation, swift3, vapor

I try to use the Vapor 2 Valid Type, but the compiler only say: "Use of undeclared type Valid".

I had read: https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/validation/package/ + https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/validation/overview/

In my my Package.swift I have defined

- /vapor/vapor.git
- /vapor/validation-provider.git
- /fluent-provider.git

as dependencies.

If I try to use `Valid<SomeValidator>` the compiler says: "Use of undeclared type Valid".

The use of `import Validation` vs `import VaporValidation` makes no difference.

Does any one have an idea how I can get Valid to work?

THX for your help.

Edit:
I created a new Vapor project `vapor new validtest --api`.

Edited the Package.swift:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "validtest",
    targets: [
        Target(name: "App"),
        Target(name: "Run", dependencies: ["App"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", majorVersion: 2),
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/validation.git", majorVersion: 1),
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/validation-provider.git", majorVersion: 1),
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-provider.git", majorVersion: 1)
    ],
    exclude: [
        "Config",
        "Database",
        "Localization",
        "Public",
        "Resources",
    ]
)
```

Ran `vapor fetch` and `vapor xcode`.

In Routes.swift from the example code I tryed this:

```
import Vapor
import FluentProvider
import Validation
// or and both imports are tested
import VaporValidation

extension Droplet {
    func setupRoutes() throws {
        get("info") { req in

            let input: Valid<OnlyAlphanumeric> = try req.data["input"].validated()
```

No matter which import I used, the compiler always say: "Use of undeclared type Valid".

Comment: FYI: `VaporValidation` was renamed to  `ValidationProvider` to match other provides with Validation Provider release v1.2.0 (July 2017). `VaporValidation` is deprecated. So, `import VaporValidation` would instead be `import ValidationProvider` for v1.2.0 or higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
let input: Valid<OnlyAlphanumeric> = try req.data["input"].validated()
```

Vapor 2's validation uses

```
guard let input = req.data["input"]?.string else { throw SomeError }
try input.validated(by: OnlyAlphanumeric())
```

If the input string is not valid, a `ValidationError` will be thrown.

Comment: THX, this solution works for me. Don't know why I haven't saw the code completion ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This should work:

```
.Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/validation.git", majorVersion: 1)

...

import Validation

...

try EmailValidator().validate(email)
```

Comment: THX for your answer. But I try to use the type Valid to ensure that no invalid values can be stored in a data model.