# undeclared type 'valid', no such module 'Validation'

Tags: validation, vapor

I was following along a screen cast from Ray Wenderlich (https://videos.raywenderlich.com/screencasts/545-server-side-swift-with-vapor-basic-validation) (which doesn't have a compilable project) when I tried to type

```
let input: Valid<OnlyAlphanumeric> = try request.data["input"].validated()
```

And the compiler told me Valid doesn't exist. I tried looking for this and found that Vapor doesn't do the validation like this anymore and that it uses different lines found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45363444/2305517
which are:

```
guard let input = req.data["input"]?.string else { throw SomeError }
try input.validated(by: OnlyAlphanumeric())
```

However strings don't have a function called validated(by:)

I tried importing Validation but the module doesn't exist.

Is there a way to complete the tutorial now? Validation doesn't appear to be in the Vapor code at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the [validation-provider](https://github.com/vapor/validation-provider) package to your project. You can do this by adding a package to the dependency array in your `Package.swift` file:

For Swift 3, you would add this:

```
.Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/validation-provider.git", majorVersion: 1)
```

In Swift 4, it would look like this:

```
.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/validation-provider.git", from: "1.0.0"),
```

Then run `vapor update`, and if you are using Xcode, `vapor xcode`.

You can then import `ValidationProvider` to the files you need it in.

Make sure you add the provider to your `config`:

```
try config.addProvider(ValidationProvider.Provider.self)
```

Comment: For those coming after me, you now (as of Vapor 3, i believe) also need to add `"ValidationProvider"`to the target dependencies. So under the target, dependencies would look like `dependencies: ["Vapor", "FluentProvider", "ValidationProvider"],`

Comment: To be correct, it is if you are on Swift 4 or later for your `Package.swift` version. Thanks for that @NateBirkholz.